# Browsing using lynx and links (text-only browser)

Tags: feature-request, usability, captcha

Does Stackoverflow support **text-only WEB-browsers**? Sometimes it is comfortable to surf using **links** or **lynx** text-only browsers, and some people use them with speech recognition programms, but it seems that SO doesn't support text-based browsers well.

For example, I have to type manually my OpenID, cannot post a question as anonymous because of "You must enter the confirmation code in the box above", but a text browser doesn't display any graphics!

It would be nice if SO will support text-based browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You want the captcha to be displayed in plain text?

Comment: yes, please (see previos, yesterdays discussions)

Comment: When captcha is displayed in plain text, then the spam bots just copy it and paste. Rendering it useless.

Comment: I'm afraid the two examples you used are **absolutely unavoidable**. One is javascript, the other requires by it's very definition an image.

Comment: Captcha's exist that do not use images.. I propose replacement questions such as "What is the sum of 4 and 5"... I'm sure you can make the English more complex and difficult to parse, but I find those kinda spam blocks to be very effective and easy on the users.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday's discussion (that is, psihodelia's feature request) was about using logic problems or riddles instead of character recognition in captchas.

Character recognition would certainly be a problem to visually-impaired users, although there is **no** suggestion this applies to psihodelia.

SO provides the option of choosing a different set of characters and/or hearing the characters used in the captcha.

psihodelia validly argues that *hearing* the characters may be a problem for users whose first language is not English.

It's not clear where the responsibility to provide accessible web sites ends. The question hasn't received judicial attention in more than a few places.

I think it must be defined *legally* as making 'a reasonable effort' and Stack Overflow does that. There will always be some users whose needs are not completely satisfied.

Sydney Olympics Accessibility complaint: http://contenu.nu/socog.html
*See the last sentence of this document*

Comment: some people use text-only browsers with speech recognition programs; text-only browsers do not display Captcha-option of hearing and they not support Adobe Flash

Comment: StackOverflow should **not have to compromise the majority** to help the minority. Removing the captcha would seriously affect the quality of content. If a person of limited sight wishes to join, they can use OpenID just fine.

Comment: What was the last sentence of that document?

Comment: The link doesn't work.  Can you sum up?  This question is 2 years old with no answer accepted.